# Difference between printing value at address in C and in GDB

Tags: c, gdb, reverse-engineering

I have been trying to get the return address from main in my program. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char buffer[64];
        printf("[%p]: ", buffer+64+8+4);
        printf("%p ", *(buffer+64+8+4));
        printf("%p ", *(buffer+64+8+5));
        printf("%p ", *(buffer+64+8+6));
        printf("%p \n", *(buffer+64+8+7));
}
```

I've added 64 to cover the buffer, 8 is for the padding (figured out via gdb) and the final 4 is for pushed ebp on the stack. The next thing in stack should be the return address for main.
Running the program yields:
`[0xbffff7dc]: 0x76 0xffffffdc 0xffffffea 0xffffffb7`

but from gdb, I get

```
(gdb) x/x 0xbffff7dc
0xbffff7dc:     0xb7eadc76
```

I can see, in the STDOUT of the program, the meaningful part of the return address is located at the LSB and all the upper bytes are 0xff (except for the 0x76, no idea why).

Comment: The reason for filling your values with `ff` is that on your system `char` is a signed value and it is first extended to size of `int` before printing. For negative values this includes "sign extension". As `0x76` is not negative, no sign bit is replicated to the upper bits.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly realized that dereferencing a pointer in C is completely dependent on the type of pointer.
Any expression of the kind `*(buffer+XXX)` would only return a single byte of data located at the address as `buffer` is a `char*` (and char is 1 byte).

The solution would be to cast the address to an `int*` (or any datatype capable of holding an address, say `char**`) *before* dereferencing.

Finally, I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char buffer[64];
        //gets(buffer);
        printf("[%p]: ", buffer+64+8+4);
        printf("%p \n", *( (char**) (buffer+64+8+4)));
}
```

which successfully outputs 
`[0xbffff7dc]: 0xb7eadc76`